# How do I modify my Python code below to append a character to the beginning of the string in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-processing

I am doing a data visualization assignment where I need to take in a dataset and make certain visualizations. Consider the following about the dataset:

- The columns are represented by longitude (list of strings with a 'E' or 'W' attached to them denoting eastern or western longitude respectively)
- The rows are represented by the latitude (a column of strings with 'N' or 'S' denoting the northern or southern latitudes respectively)

So I have to read the dataset, convert the latitudes with 'N' attached to them into positive float values and 'S' attached to them as negative float values (the whole data is in string).

Similarly, I have to convert the longitudes with 'E' attached to them into positive float values and 'W' attached to them as negative float values.

Since I am new to Python, Pandas, Numpy I am having a lot of difficulties to achieve the same. I have so far been able to convert the latitudes and longitudes in string format into float format and get rid of the 'N', 'S', 'E', 'W' characters respectively. However, I am unable to figure out how do I make the float values positive or negative based on the characters ('N', 'S', 'E', 'W') prior to float conversion.
Below is the code I have written so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Aug-2016-potential-temperature-180x188.txt", skiprows = range(7))
df.columns = ["longitude"]
df = df.longitude.str.split("\t", expand = True)
smaller = df.iloc[::10,:]

print(df.head(10), end = "\n")
print(smaller, end = "\n")
print(df.iloc[1][3], end = "\n")
print(smaller.iloc[2][175], end = "\n")

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('~/documents/datasets/viz_a1/Aug-2016-potential-temperature-180x188.txt', skiprows=7)
data.columns = ['longitudes']
data = data['longitudes'].str.split('\t', expand=True)
df = data.iloc[::10,:]
df.head()

# replace 'E' with '' and 'W' with ''
df.loc[0] = df.loc[0].str.replace('E', '').str.replace('W', '')

# convert the longitude values to float values (THIS ONE WORKS)
df.loc[0] = df.loc[0][1:].astype(float)

# replace 'S' with '' and 'N' with ''
df.loc[:][0] = df.loc[:][0].str.replace('S', '').str.replace('N', '')

# convert latitude values into float values (THIS ONE DOES NOT WORK!!)
df.loc[:][0] = df.loc[:][0].astype(float)

# checking if the float values exist
print(df.loc[0][2], ' data-type ', type(df.loc[0][2])) # columns converted into float
print(df.loc[30][0], ' data-type ', type(df.loc[30][0])) # rows not converted into float
```

**Doubts:**

- How do I convert the values into positive and negative float values based on symbol ('S', 'W' represent -ve float values and 'E', 'N' represent positive float values)
- How do I successfully convert the latitudes into float values (the code I wrote did not convert the rows into floats; did not throw any error also!)

*P.S.* The conversions for longitudes was generating a lot of warnings. Would be nice if someone could explain why am I getting those warnings and how to prevent them? (again, I am new to Python and Pandas!)

The dataset can be found [here](https://github.com/enigma6174/ml-datasets)

Here is a screenshot of the dataset:
[image: screenshot of the data just after putting it in data-frame]

Comment: You can use startswith to check the specific character(s) and replace with the positive and negative signs. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html

Comment: Can you provide some example data? Just the first few rows would suffice

Comment: @asongtoruin I have edited the question and added a picture of the Jupyter notebook which contains the output of `df.head()`

Comment: You shouldn't post code as screenshots - if you post it as text, someone trying to answer your question can copy it directly and have something to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add a few more arguments in the read_csv function to get a dataframe in which the columns are the longitudinal strings and the index is the latitude. The data in your dataframe is now the raster data

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'Aug-2016-potential-temperature-180x188.txt',
                 skiprows=8, delimiter='\t', index_col=0)
```

Then I would convert the longitudinal strings, the columns of the dataframe, to floats with the following code:

```
column_series = pd.Series(df.columns)
df.columns = column_series.apply(lambda x: float(x.replace('E','')) if x.endswith('E') else -float(x.replace('W','')))
```

After I convert the latitude strings, the index of the dataframe, to floats with this code:

```
index_series  = pd.Series(df.index)
df.index = index_series.apply(lambda x: float(x.replace('N','')) if x.endswith('N') else -float(x.replace('S','')))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It was the most helpful solution. Just one thing, could you give a brief explanation how the _x_ in the lambda function operates on the individual values of rows and columns (I mean I got the logic of converting it into float based on character but how exactly is _x_ **getting the values** to read? We are not passing any form of list or variables to it. Actually this is the only part that confuses me, I figured out the explanation of the remainder of your code using online documentation.

Comment: With the .apply method you can apply a function to every value of a pandas series, x is the argument of the function. In this case x is the value in the pandas series. Applying the lambda function to your series will apply this function to every value in the series. It might help to have a look at the examples here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the cleanest, but you could replace 'N' and 'E' with "", then use np.where to replace 'S' and 'W', convert to float, and multiply by -1

I made an example df where I apply this procedure to the first column

```
example = pd.DataFrame({'1':['S35', 'E24', 'N45', 'W66'],
           '2': ['E45', 'N78', 'S12', 'W22']})

example
Out[153]: 
     1    2
0  S35  E45
1  E24  N78
2  N45  S12
3  W66  W22

col = example.loc[:, '1']

col = col.str.replace('N|E', "")

col
Out[156]: 
0    S35
1     24
2     45
3    W66
Name: 1, dtype: object

example.loc[:,'1'] = np.where(col.str.contains('W|S'), col.str.replace('W|S', '').astype('float') * -1, col)


example
Out[158]: 
    1    2
0 -35  E45
1  24  N78
2  45  S12
3 -66  W22
```